# PHP: session | Failed to decode session object

Tags: php, symfony, sylius

I try to add e-commerce features into a legacy project, so I still need my old session-handler. I use PHP v7.1.14 and Session2DB (https://github.com/voku/session2db/tree/4.0.0) in this project. Now I have a strange problem with this "Legacy Project" + Symfony 3.4.4 + Sylius 1.1.0 and the session handling.

Symfony session config:

```
session:
    storage_id: session.storage.php_bridge
    handler_id: ~
```

Info: https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/session/php_bridge.html

Error: if I try to login into the admin view of Sylius, I see this error

> session_start(): Failed to decode session object. Session has been
>   destroyed

... any idea how I can debug / fix this?

EDIT: If I try to use native php session handling in the legacy project + the above Symfony config I get the following error. So I think the decode error is something in Session2DB.

> Failed to unserialize the security token from the session.

... maybe any idea how I can debug / fix this?

Comment: What kind of data are you storing in the sessions? Is it unicode characters by chance?

Comment: Yes by chance there is also unicode, but the database and the database connection etc. is using utf8mb4.

Comment: How about `serialize()`ing? My guess is that the session handler (`Session2DB`) somehow can't read the data in the session.

Comment: yes maybe... I found a old blog post about "legacy-session" + Symfony here -> http://tech.trivago.com/2015/08/26/writing-to-legacy-session/ and they also recommend to check the "session_encode" from php.

Answer (score 1):

Im my case, the reason of error was non-encoded output of `random_bytes()` function stored in session variable.